# Android Surfaceview onClick Event doesnt work after pressing HOME

Tags: android, surfaceview

i  have used game loop as given in tutorial

http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-vii,220.html

when i press home button and comes again to surfaceview , onclickview  doesnt works after that

Answer (score 0):

How do you try to click? Are you using a trackball/dpad or the touchscreen? If you are using a trackball/dpad, make sure the SurfaceView is focusable and focusable in touch mode (see View.setFocusable/setFocusableInTouchMode).

Comment: i had already done that , i want taht touch also work after onResume is called .

Comment: it stops working after when i press home , or any call is there . Rest its working fine